# Convert Column S quantitites to Ton by refering the Column T and tons to tons and rest 0, should i use if find or should i used if search formula plzh

Tags: excel, if-statement

[image]

Convert quantity kg to tons and tons to tons and rest should be 0 in single formula

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be on mobile, and I am not sure which functions are supported on the app.  You can try any of these:

```
=IF(T2="METRIC TON",S2,IF(T2="KILOGRAMS",S2/1000,0))

=SWITCH(T2,"METRIC TON",S2,"KILOGRAMS",S2/1000,0)

=IFS(T2="METRIC TON",S2,T2="KILOGRAMS",S2/1000,TRUE,0)
```

Comment: For question purpose i used mobile app but anyway thank you so much jody its solved